# Problem to configure Debugging PHP with Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, wamp, xdebug

I'm trying configure XDebug on VS Code following this tutorial:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nicktrog/2016/02/11/configuring-visual-studio-code-for-php-development/

but in this point:

[image]

The vs code not show the PHP option.

I tried reinstall VS Code and XDebug. 
I tried to reinstall the php server and change de PHP Server but nothing work.

I founded others tutorials but show-me the same problem: When i click on gear just show the launch.json without php option

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a configuration through the drop down available?

Comment: yes, but i dont know if was correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For myself, the gear icon did nothing too, so to generate the required PHP configuration I toggled the drop down and clicked **Add Configuration** and it setup two PHP configurations in `launch.json`:

```
{
    "name": "Listen for XDebug",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "port": 9000
},
{
    "name": "Launch currently open script",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
    "port": 9000
}
```

Both of those two configuration are the sames ones that would've been generated by clicking the gear icon (had it worked) as is confirmed by the **PHP Debug** extension documentation:

**Listen for XDebug**

> Listen for XDebug This setting will simply start listening on the specified port (by default 9000) for XDebug. If you configured XDebug like recommended above, everytime you make a request with a browser to your webserver or launch a CLI script XDebug will connect and you can stop on breakpoints, exceptions etc.

**Launch currently open script**

> Launch currently open script This setting is an example of CLI debugging. It will launch the currently opened script as a CLI, show all stdout/stderr output in the debug console and end the debug session once the script exits.

Secondly, ensure that you have setup the **PHP Debug** extension correctly as per the instructions:

> This extension is a debug adapter between VS Code and XDebug by Derick Rethan. XDebug is a PHP extension (a .so file on Linux and a .dll on Windows) that needs to be installed on your server.
>
> Install XDebug I highly recommend you make a simple test.php file, put a phpinfo(); statement in there, then copy the output and paste it into the XDebug installation wizard. It will analyze it and give you tailored installation instructions for your environment. In short:
>
> On Windows: Download the appropiate precompiled DLL for your PHP version, architecture (64/32 Bit), thread safety (TS/NTS) and Visual Studio compiler version and place it in your PHP extension folder.
>   On Linux: Either download the source code as a tarball or clone it with git, then compile it.
>   Configure PHP to use XDebug by adding zend_extension=path/to/xdebug to your php.ini. The path of your php.ini is shown in your phpinfo() output under "Loaded Configuration File".
>
> Enable remote debugging in your php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

> There are other ways to tell XDebug to connect to a remote debugger than remote_autostart, like cookies, query parameters or browser extensions. I recommend remote_autostart because it "just works". There are also a variety of other options, like the port (by default 9000), please see the XDebug documentation on remote debugging for more information.
>
> If you are doing web development, don't forget to restart your webserver to reload the settings.
>
> Verify your installation by checking your phpinfo() output for an XDebug section.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Solved like this:
i upgraded to  the lastest version of ddev , I also deleted my vscode configuration file and remade it. IT WORKS NOW